# How to open app with an url specific react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm following this tutorial:

```
https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e
```

but my app doesn't lunched when I type this url at browser:

```
peopleapp://people/0
```

my `manifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*.*.*"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:supportsRtl="false"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="peopleapp" android:host="people" />
        </intent-filter>


      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
          <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="teamcide"/>


  <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyDpiU78-****S6Lvllgqo"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a small quirk with Android and deep links and that is putting the link in your browser won't work. There are a couple of ways that you can open the link.

## Tutorial

In the tutorial it says the following about opening it on an Android device:

> That is all we need as far as configuration goes. To test this out,
>   open Android Studio. Open Run -> Edit Configurations and change the
>   launch options to URL, passing in the following url:
>   peopleapp://people/1

[image: android studio debug config]

## App from the Play Store

You can use the following app to open your deep links https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manoj.dlt

## Create a webpage

You can create a small webpage with your deep link contained inside an href

```
<a href="peopleapp://people/0">open people 0</a>
```

And then browse to that page and click your link.

Answer (score 2):

Hii you can use following code to open specific url in react native

```
const url = 'whatsapp://';
Linking.canOpenURL(url)
.then(supported => {
  if (!supported) {
    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(url);
  }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Or you can also check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) url for more information